# Arranging/displaying the Y-axis' values in descending order from the top

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

As mentioned in the title. Was wondering if anyone could help me? The values of the y-axis are arranged in descending order from the bottom, instead of the top.

Refer to this screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ylim`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xValues = list(range(10))
quads = [x** 2 for x in xValues]
plt.ylim(max(quads), 0)
plt.plot(xValues, quads)
plt.show()
```

or `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xValues = list(range(10))
quads = [x** 2 for x in xValues]
plt.plot(xValues, quads)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]